# Perl string contains bracket

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace

I have a question. I have a variable that contains brackets for example:

```
Local $string = "abc[0].xzy"
```

Now I want to search for all strings in a file that matches that string `$string`. The problem is that the string contains a bracket and I can't change the to `abc\[0\]\.xzy`. Is there a solution to solve my problem?

Comment: It is `local` not `Local` (if Local is not a subroutine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `\Q` `\E` block (quotemeta) which treats all the chars present inside the block as literal chars.

```
/\Q$string\E/
```

[Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: i know. But if i want to except an answer the systems said you have to wait x minutes to accept :)